# JQUERYUI Autocomplete with json does not work

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have the following code using jqueryui and in the autocomplete box i see list but it doesn't show the content. The list has height of 0.

data is a json and i can see the data before the binding. Not sure what i am missing here.

```
         $("#Stock").autocomplete({
             dataType: "json",
             source: data,
             autoFill: true,
             minLength: 1,

             position: { my: "left to[", at: "left bottom", collision: "none" },
             select: function (event, ui) {
                 alert(ui.item.Symbol)
             },


             open: function (e, ui) {
                 console.log($(".ui-autocomplete li").size());
             },
             search: function (e, ui) {
                 console.log("search returned: " + $(".ui-autocomplete li").size());

             },
             close: function (e, ui) {
                 console.log("on close" + $(".ui-autocomplete li").size());
                 $("#Stock").val("");
             }

         });
```

I have added the issue i am facing here.. Any help is much appreciated..

http://jsfiddle.net/BJGLf/

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are passing `[{Symbol: 'value'}]` and the autocomplete is expecting `['value','value']` or `[{ label: 'label', value: 'value' }, { label: 'label2', value: 'value2' }]`. Refer to the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) for the source formats.